# tf.contrib.layers.layer_norm with tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell

Tags: tensorflow

I have multiple RNN layers right now setup like:

```
    stack = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([
        tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(num_hidden, activation=clipped_relu)
        for _ in range(num_rnn_layers)
    ])
```

But am trying to add layer normalization using https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/layer_norm to the RNN layers. I've tried a number of different setups but can't get the model to compile.

Has anyone done this yet? And if so, how did you implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a layer normalization implementation here:

`tf.contrib.rnn.LayerNormBasicLSTMCell`

which can be used in the `MultiRNNCell` function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define your own layer class that normalizes inside the call function. Did you try that?